# How to reverse x-axis?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am using core-plot and need to reverse x-axis such that it starts at `5000` and ends at `0`. How I can do this?

Here is my x-axis range,

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(500)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of this in the Plot Gallery app (Plot Space Demo).  If you look at the corresponding code in PlotSpaceDemo.m, the negative axis is set up like so:

```
...

CPTXYPlotSpace *negativeLinearPlotSpace = [[[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init] autorelease];
negativeLinearPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(100) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(-100)];
negativeLinearPlotSpace.yRange = linearPlotSpace.yRange;

[graph removePlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
[graph addPlotSpace:negativeLinearPlotSpace];

CPTXYAxis *negativeLinearAxis = [[[CPTXYAxis alloc] init] autorelease];
negativeLinearAxis.plotSpace                   = negativeLinearPlotSpace;
//The rest of the set up is just formatting labels, ticks, etc.
...
```

So for your case, you'd declare the location with 5000 and the length of -5000 like so:

```
negativeLinearPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(5000) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(-5000)];
//Add plot space to the graph
//assign plot space to the x axis
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(5000)]; // Or set it -5000
```